# I already added start script but still having missing script error in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

- I already add in started script

2018-09-07T07:28:11.972556+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting

2018-09-07T07:28:15.636176+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`

2018-09-07T07:28:19.029735+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1

2018-09-07T07:28:19.083882+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2018-09-07T07:28:18.920980+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start

2018-09-07T07:28:18.937291+00:00 app[web.1]:

2018-09-07T07:28:18.937396+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

2018-09-07T07:28:18.937499+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-09-07T07_28_18_926Z-debug.log

[Start Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgBlB.png)

Comment: Do you specify the start in `package.json` and is it at the root of your project?

Comment: Yes I did.
"main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },

Comment: 2 steps to simulate locally what is happen when u push to heroku.. 1  re-install node_modules locally by doing rm -rf * in the node_modules folder , followed by  'npm install'... 2  use 'heroku local' to start a local run using the 'start' script and or the procfile

Comment: @Robert I got this when I follow your method 
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
2:28:29 PM web.1 |  Server has started
2:28:29 PM web.1 |  (node:62397) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.

Comment: @RobertRowntree I still have the same problem when I push to heroku

Comment: on the remote, maybe its running , or looking for the start script BEFORE the install is complete. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support   search on 'postinstall'

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. There was a conflict with my local git repo and heroku repo. After I remove my local git repo, I was able to upload on heroku with no error.

Thank you guys for your help.